# How to use MultiDex with a custom Application class?

Tags: android

Ok so I am making an App that has uses the .App class to get Context statically, the class does not work unless placed in manifest under 
    `<application android:name=.App` but the issue is I clocked 65k so I have multiDex and MultiDex too needs to be in Manifest under the `<application android:name=.MultiDex` otherwise my App will not run, how can I get past this problem without affected multidex which is my worst fear looking at how much trouble I went through just to make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [this page](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html):

> **Note**: If your app uses extends the Application class, you can override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex. For more information, see the MultiDexApplication reference documentation.

In other words, use your own App class but add the following:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: @SindyMcMore - So if in my `<Manifest>` -  `<application android:name = ".Singleton">` and in each activity (or java class) I will `@Override attachBaseContext`, Is this what you mean?

Comment: @RoCk, no, you only add the attachBaseContext function to your class that extends Application.

Comment: OR, you could just extend the MultiDexApplication class instead of just Application.

Answer (score 1):

BaseAppplication is custom Application class

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            // your custom code here
        }



    // Add multidex Code or other Application Class here 
        @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
            super.attachBaseContext(base);
            MultiDex.install(this);
        }
    }
```