# Managing multiple Application classes- Volley + MultiDex

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, android-volley

My app crossed the 65K limit after adding google play dependencies. So I had to enable multidex and add this to manifest

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

But there is also a singleton class of volley that extends application since I need to get context of that class.

How can both be managed? Is there a way to make the volley class static? The volley class code is :

```
public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class
        .getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    getRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                new LruBitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
}
```

And the usage of the class is :

```
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, "Making a request");
```

If it can be made static then what should be the implementation of the class to make network calls?

Comment: Provide the Gradle dependencies used. Why google play service is used? Means what is the google play service dependency in your application?

Comment: Hi. I've solved the issue. Decreased the play dependencies to the only useful one.

Comment: mInstance = this; this line in onCreate complains in Sonar analysis. It's not the correct way. Can someone suggest how to fix that?

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't get that. What do you mean by complains in sonar analysis?

Answer (score 0):

try this, just override this method in your Appcontroller class.link :[How to use MultiDex with a custom Application class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590009/how-to-use-multidex-with-a-custom-application-class)

```
               @Override
      protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
      {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

use

public class AppController extends MultiDexApplication

instead of

public class AppController extends Application